# Capture row information if the column value becomes NULL in ORACLE

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql

I want to capture some information from different tables after a column in table A becomes NULL and then subsequently send it via email.
I can do that email part.

I am not able to fetch only that particular row.
below is my code.

```
Table name : null_test
Col1    Col2
-----  ------
A1  10
B1  20
C1  30
```

When the value in col1 becomes null I want to capture that row ONLY in the cursor

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trig_null_flag
   AFTER UPDATE OF col1
   ON null_test
   REFERENCING NEW AS NEW OLD AS OLD
   FOR EACH ROW
   WHEN(NEW.col1 IS NULL)
DECLARE
 PRAGMA autonomous_transaction;
  CURSOR cur
    IS SELECT DISTINCT :NEW.col1 AS col1,:NEW.col2 AS col2 FROM null_test;
BEGIN
Email structure...
            l_mail_conn := utl_smtp.open_connection(l_mailhost, 25);
            utl_smtp.helo(l_mail_conn, l_mailhost);
   ...
   ..
 FOR rec IN cur
               LOOP
                  utl_smtp.write_data(l_mail_conn, rec.col1||CHR(166)||rec.col2||crlf);
               END LOOP;
            utl_smtp.close_data(l_mail_conn );
            utl_smtp.quit(l_mail_conn);
```

Comment: 1) what are you trying to reach using SELECT * FROM null_test
    WHERE :NEW.col1 is NULL; ? :NEW.COL1 in your particular query always NULL, this is VALUE, not a COLUMN. Hence you get all rows from the table. 2) The idea of the design is poor. First of all transactions are ISOLATED, and you will not be able to see changes what are not committed. In theory you can use ROWID (quite poor idea too) to identify the row you need, but this does not give you a clue for the case when the transaction will be rolled back - then your trigger will send wrong message.

Comment: Yes you are right,if it rollbacks the email will still be sent,in other words trigger will file.My select statement is wrong it should be SELECT DISTINCT :NEW.col1 AS col1,:NEW.col2 AS col2 FROM null_test

Comment: @DmitryNikiforov  Thanks for the reply, I was in mixed up with some other stuff and completely goofed up the select statement.Sometimes i miss simple stuff.

Comment: @DmitryNikiforov , how do I use the ROWID

Comment: @DmitryNikiforov I found out.. thanks again..Sorry for so many messages

Answer (score 0):

Why aren't you getting row's values from "NEW" directly?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trig_null_flag
   AFTER UPDATE OF col1
   ON null_test
   REFERENCING NEW AS NEW OLD AS OLD
   FOR EACH ROW
   WHEN(NEW.col1 IS NULL)
DECLARE
 PRAGMA autonomous_transaction;

 Email structure...
            l_mail_conn := utl_smtp.open_connection(l_mailhost, 25);
            utl_smtp.helo(l_mail_conn, l_mailhost); 
            utl_smtp.write_data(l_mail_conn, /*here-->>*/ new.col2 || CHR(166) || /*here-->>*/ new.col3 /* etc...*/ || crlf); -- no need to put col1, 'cause you know that it's null!! So put all other columns
            utl_smtp.close_data(l_mail_conn );
            utl_smtp.quit(l_mail_conn);
```